# M regular surface if $rank\frac{\partial \left(\Psi ^1\left(x\right),..,\Psi \:^s\left(x\right)\right)\:}{\partial \left(x^1,..,x^s\right)\:}=s$,why?

Tags: manifolds, surfaces

We had this definition for a regular surface given:

> We say that a set $M=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\::\:\Psi ^{\nu }\left(x\right)=0,\:\nu =1,\:...,\:n\right\}$ where $\Psi \:^{\nu \:}:\:\mathbb{R}^n\:\rightarrow \:\mathbb{R}$ are smooth functions defines a regular surface if $rank\frac{\partial \left(\Psi ^1\left(x\right),..,\Psi \:^s\left(x\right)\right)\:}{\partial \left(x^1,..,x^s\right)\:}=s$ (for $x\in M$)

Could someone maybe give me an example to understand this definition intuitively?

Comment: The index ranges look a little strange.  Are you sure $\nu$ goes from $1$ to $n$?

Comment: I've written it down as from 1 to n, maybe it should be from 1 to s, but idk

Comment: Ok, it's 1,...,s where s<n

Comment: The set $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by the $s$ equations $\Psi^1(x) = 0, \ldots, \Psi^s(x) = 0$.  So, you'd ideally like to say that $M$ is an $(n-s)$-dimensional "smooth shape" inside $\mathbb{R}^n$.  However, this isn't always true.  For example, $M = \{x^2 + y^2 = 0\}$ is defined by one equation in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but it's just the origin (not a curve).  Similarly, $M = \{xy = 0\}$ is defined by one equation in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but it's a pair of lines that meet at $(0,0)$, so it's not "smooth" at $(0,0)$.  The rank condition guarantees that $M$ will be a smooth $(n-s)$-dim shape.

Comment: But M is basically a set of points where our Psis will be equal to 0, right? This is what I can't imagine, how can such a set become a shape?

Comment: Here's the simplest example I can think of.  We often say that $y = 2x + 3$ is a line with slope $2$, but of course that's not quite true: $y = 2x + 3$ is just an equation, not a shape.  In saying that $y = 2x + 3$ is a line with slope $2$, what we really mean is that the set of points $M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon y - 2x - 3 = 0\}$ is a line with slope $2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  The same thing goes for the "parabola" $y - x^2 = 0$ or the "circle" $x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$.

Comment: Ok now I get it, thanks. But why is this condition with the rank important here?

Comment: As it is said above, the rank condition assures that everything will be smooth. The mathematical explanation is the implicit function theorem - or equivalently, the inverse function theorem.